# Can anyone help me make a pseudocode that can traverse this heap in increasing order?

Tags: heap, traversal

This is the heap.

[Min_Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ660.png)
The answer should look like this [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15].
I do know for a fact that it repeats, but still having a hard time formulating pseudocode for this problem.

Comment: You need to understand how binary heaps work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for removing the smallest item from a binary heap:

1. Take the root element (this is the smallest)
2. Move the lowest, right-most item from the heap to the root.
3. If the new node has no children, or it is smaller than both of its children, then you're done.
4. If the new node is larger than either of its children, swap it with the smallest child.
5. Go to step 3.

Repeat those steps until the heap is empty.

In your heap, you have:

```
                     1
              /             \
             3               2
          /     \         /     \
         7       5       6       4
       /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
      15   11 13    9 14   10 12    8
```

So you remove the value 1, and replace the root with 8, giving you:

```
                     8
              /             \
             3               2
          /     \         /     \
         7       5       6       4
       /   \   /   \   /   \   / 
      15   11 13    9 14   10 12
```

8 is larger than both of its children, so you swap with the smallest child, 2:

```
                     2
              /             \
             3               8
          /     \         /     \
         7       5       6       4
       /   \   /   \   /   \   / 
      15   11 13    9 14   10 12
```

Again, 8 is larger than both of its children, so you swap with the smallest, 4:

```
                     2
              /             \
             3               4
          /     \         /     \
         7       5       6       8
       /   \   /   \   /   \   / 
      15   11 13    9 14   10 12
```

And you're done because 8 is smaller than its only child, 12.

To remove the next item, you remove the 2, replace it with 12, and move 12 down the heap according to the rules. The result is:

```
                     3
              /             \
             5               4
          /     \         /     \
         7       9       6       8
       /   \   /   \   /   \
      15   11 13   12 14   10
```